# javascript not saving in blogger

Tags: javascript, error-handling, blogger

i recently founded a code on github as follows :-

```
    function showDashBoard(){
      for(var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        $('.col'+i).each(function(){
            $(this).addClass('fadeInForward-'+i).removeClass('fadeOutback');
        });
      }
    }

    function fadeDashBoard(){
      for(var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        $('.col'+i).addClass('fadeOutback').removeClass('fadeInForward-'+i);
      }
    }
    // fadeDashBoard();

    $(".lock-thumb").click(function(){
        fadeDashBoard();
        $('.login-screen').addClass('slidePageInFromLeft').removeClass('slidePageBackLeft');
    });

    $('#unlock-button').click(function(){
          $('.login-screen').removeClass('slidePageInFromLeft').addClass('slidePageBackLeft');
          showDashBoard();
    });

  $('.big, .small').each(function(){
    var $this= $(this),
        page = $this.data('page');
    $this.on('click',function(){
      $('.page.'+page).addClass('openpage');
      fadeDashBoard();
    })
  });
  $('.close-button').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().addClass('slidePageLeft')
          .one('webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend', function(e) {
                $(this).removeClass('slidePageLeft').removeClass('openpage');
              });
      showDashBoard();
  });
```

but on saving the code , i found the error as : -

Error parsing XML, line 9, column 25: The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.

please ,help me with the code , by finding the error.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that for some reason your JavaScript is parsed by an XML parser.

Assuming that script is within a `<script>` tag put everything inside that tag within a CDATA section:

```
<script>
// <![CDATA[
    // put your JS here
// ]]>
</script>
```

Another (better) option would be storing your JS in a separate file and then including it using

```
<script src="whatever.js"></script>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier (and better for caching) to just move the JS to a `.js` file in that case?

Comment: Indeed, but I have no clue if he can create additional files there or if he'd have to host it somewhere external.

Comment: I see, +1 for the CDATA block.